# OSL component names for points, colors? (x, y, z, r, g, b)

Tags: osl

The [Open Shading Language spec](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/doc/osl-languagespec.pdf) says

> Color variables may also have their components referenced using “named components” that look like accessing structure fields named `r`, `g`, and `b`, as synonyms for [0], [1], and [2], respectively:
>
> ```
> float green = C.g; // get the green component  
> C.r = 0.5;         // set the red component
> ```

It says the same thing about points and x, y, z components. This is not working for me in Blender 2.8. I get errors like:

> error: type 'point' does not have a member 'x'

Is this not implemented in Blender?

Comment: I'm not trying to use another OSL shader; I'm learning the language so I can write my own. It's not a show-stopper to write `p[0]`, `p[1]`, etc. I just find `p.x`, `p.y` to be clearer to read. Maybe I should just report it in the Blender bug tracker and see what they say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The syntax was introduced in version 1.11](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/CHANGES.md) of the Open Shading Language (OSL) specification.

> OSL Language and oslc compiler:
>
> - New syntax to reference color and point/vector/normal components as named struct components, such as C.r, C.g, C.b, or P.x, P.y, P.z. #1049 (1.11.0)

[Blender 2.83 is using OSL 1.10.9](https://developer.blender.org/rBb9c9b001710ab60b448e92550e04aaae48f39452) and thus doesn't support this syntax yet.